# Get camera Feed with flashlight

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, concurrency, camera, flashlight

I'm actually trying to develop an Android app using Unity3d (I have no choice :p).
My problem is, how can i retrieve the Android camera feed and also turn on the flashlight.

I have the following code to turn on the flash light (it works with "native access") :

```
AndroidJavaObject cameraParameters = this.camera.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getParameters");
cameraParameters.Call("setFlashMode", "torch");
this.camera.Call("setParameters", cameraParameters);
this.camera.Call("startPreview");
```

And I have the following code to get the camera feed (it works with "unity access") :

```
var deviceName = WebCamTexture.devices[0].name;
webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture(deviceName, 1280, 720, 30);
webcamTexture.Play();
data = new Color32[webcamTexture.width * webcamTexture.height];
webcamTexture.GetPixels32 (data);
Debug.Log (data[383650].ToString());
```

But if I use the first 4 lines to turn on the flashlight, the next 6 lines does not work. If I remove the first 4 lines, the code which get camera feed works. I think it's about concurrency...

I have two choices : to find a way to turn on flash light using "unity access" (after 4 hours of google scrolling I don't have the answer) or using "java access" to get camera feed (same 4 hours of google scrolling).

Thank you for your answer !

Comment: did you find the solution? I start thinking that its not even possible unless writing a java android thing as unity plugin, doing all this natively without webcamtexture

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access both the camera Feed of a WebCamTexture as well as turning on Torch for the same "capture session" - you must get an instance of the android camera and turn it on.

You can use something like Camera Capture Kit (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56673) to achieve what you want since it features a way to turn on the Torch / flash light as extensions to the WebCamTexture.

Turning on the Torch would be something like

```
webCamTexture.SetTorchEnabled( true );
```

(Camera Capture Kit extends the WebCamTexture with such functionality for iOS/Android.)

This is an example of the Java code (from AndroidPlugin.zip) that's included to locate and return the Unity Camera referance if you want to add sometihng like SetTorchEnabled(true) yourself.

```
Class clsPlayer = Class.forName("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        Field fCurrentActivity = clsPlayer.getDeclaredField("currentActivity");
        fCurrentActivity.setAccessible(true);
        com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity currentActivity = (com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity)fCurrentActivity.get(null);
        ret.playerActivity = currentActivity;

        Field fPlayer = currentActivity.getClass().getDeclaredField("mUnityPlayer");
        fPlayer.setAccessible(true);
        com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer player = (com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer)fPlayer.get(currentActivity);
        ret.player = player;

        Field f = player.getClass().getDeclaredField("y");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        java.util.ArrayList cameraArrays = (java.util.ArrayList)f.get( player );
        int sz = cameraArrays.size();
```

This code would have to be included in an Android plugin for Unity or rewritten as "Unity Java c# Plugin code" in a C# based plugin.

This is the code that enables the Torch.

```
static public void UnityCamera_SetTorchEnabledImpl( boolean value ) {
    ResolveObjectsResult ret = UnityCaptureResolveObjects();
    Camera.Parameters params = ret.camera.getParameters();

    boolean torchSupported = false;
    if( params.getSupportedFlashModes()!=null && params.getSupportedFlashModes().contains(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH) ) {
        if(verbose)Log.d("Unity","CameraCaptureKit: FLASH_MODE_TORCH supported.");
        torchSupported = true;
    }

    // Torh..
    if( torchSupported == true ) {
        if( value == true ) {
            if(verbose)Log.d("Unity","CameraCaptureKit: turning torch on");
            params.setFlashMode( android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH );
            ret.camera.setParameters(params);
        } else {
            if(verbose)Log.d("Unity","CameraCaptureKit: turning torch off");
            params.setFlashMode( android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF );
            ret.camera.setParameters(params);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("Unity", "CameraCaptureKit: Torch not supported");
        //Log.d("Unity", "CameraCaptureKit: Applying Camera parameters");
    }

    //Log.d("Unity", "CameraCaptureKit: Applying Camera parameters");
}
```

Comment: sad that camera capture kit is no longer lives in assest store. cant find a replacement for  it....